# Reactjs render component only when ALL its child done thier render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "slow" loading issue in one of my pages.
That page contains a "root" component - let's call it `Container`.

My Container makes 2 `fetch` calls upon a value selection from a dropdown list.
The fetched data (`A` and `B`) are passed to a child component (`Board`).

Board is built from 2 unrelated components - `Player` and `Item` and they use `A` and `B` respectively as initial data.

It so happens that the `Player`s render process is much more heavy than `Item`'s.

The result is that Item is rendered on the page and after some few seconds Player is rendered also.

My wish is to see both rendering at the same time - how can I achieve that?

I guess it is something should be done by `Board` but how?

It is also important that this "waiting" will take place every time the value from the droplist is changed (it always there for the users to choose).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1) Use graphql to orchestrate the loading of data, so that the page renders when all of the data is available

2) Set state values for playerDataReady and itemDataReady. If either of these is false, display a loading spinner. When they are both true (as a result of ajax calls being resolved), then the render will do both at the same time

In the constructor...

```
  state = {
    playerDataReady: false,
    itemDataReady: false,
  }

   :
   :
componentDidMount() {
// Request player data, using axios or fetch
   axios.get(...)
   .then(data) {
     this.data = data
     this.setState({playerDataReady:true})
   }
// Do the same for your item data (and update itemDataReady)
}
```

In your render function:

```
render() {
  if (!playerDataReady || !itemDataReady) {
    return <Loader/>
  //  The data has arrived, so render it as normal...
    return ....
```

You can fill in the details

Comment: Thanks, I rather prefer to use the Reactish way before using 3rd party tool. Do you know any?

Comment: Can you please supply an example for the second way? I am not sure how to make such call to realize render has finished.